# Postgres performance improvement and checklist

Tags: sql, hibernate, database-performance, postgresql-9.2, fillfactor

I'm studing a series of issues related to **performance** of my **application** written in *Java*, which has about ***100,000 hits per day*** and each visit on average from 5 to 10 readings/writings on the 2 principale database tables (divided equally) whose cardinality is for both between **1 and 3 million records** (i access to DB via hibernate).

My two main tables store user information (about 60 columns of type varchar, integer and timestamptz) and another linked to the data to be displayed (with about 30 columns here mainly varchar, integer, timestamptz).

The main problem I encountered may have had a ***drop in performance*** of my site (let's talk about time loads over 5 seconds which obviously ***does not depend only on the database performance***), is the use of **FillFactor** which is currently the **default value of 100** (that it's used always when data not changing..).

Obviously fill factor it's same on index (there are 10 for each 2 tables of type btree)

Currently on my main tables I make

- 40% select operations
- 30% update operations
- 20% operations insert
- 10% delete operations.

My database is also made ​​up of 40 other tables of minor importance (there is just others 3 with same cardinality of user).

My questions are:

- How do you **find the right value of the fill factor** to be set ?
- Which can be a **checklist** of tasks to be checked to **improve** the **performance**
  of a database of this kind?

Database is on server dedicated (16GB Ram, 8 Core) and storage it's on SSD disk (data are backupped all days and moved on another storage)

Comment: You can go through this wiki page: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization I also highly recommend the "Postgres High Performance Book". Really worth buying.

Answer (score 0):

You have likely hit the "knee" of your memory usage where the entire index of the heavily used tables no longer fits in shared memory, so disk I/O is slowing it down.  Confirm by checking if disk I/O is higher than normal.  If so, try increasing shared memory (shared_buffers), or if that's already maxed, adjust the system shared memory size or add more system memory so you can bump it higher.  You'll also probably have to start adjusting temp buffers, work memory and maintenance memory, and WAL parameters like checkpoint_segments, etc.

There are some perf tuning hints on PostgreSQL.org, and Google is your friend.

*Edit:* (to address the first comment)  The first symptom of not-enough-memory is a big drop in performance, everything else being the same.  Changing the table fill factor is not going to make a difference if you hit a knee in memory usage, if anything it will make it worse w.r.t. load times (which I assume means "db reads") because row information will be expanded across more pages on disk with blank space in each page thus more disk I/O is needed for table scans.  But fill factor less than 100% can help with UPDATE operations, but I've found adjusting WAL parameters can compensate most of the time when using indexes (unless you've already optimized those).  Bottom line, you need to profile all the heavy queries using EXPLAIN to see what will help.  But at first glance, I'm pretty certain this is a memory issue even with the database on an SSD.  We're talking a lot of random reads and random writes and a lot of SSDs actually get *worse* than HDDs after a lot of random small writes.

Comment: Clustering/partitioning those tables could be a solution (with FillFactor to 100)?